# Undocumented API endpoints: users.channelSections.channels.bulkUpdate, users.channelSections.create

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am trying to build an automation that will move my Slack channels to different sidebar sections depending upon strings present within the channel names. I haven't found public-facing API documentation that covers any endpoints related to sidebar sections, but I did observe the following when testing with section manipulation in Slack's browser application:

`users.channelSections.channels.bulkUpdate`

```
Method: POST
Request URL: https://<workspace>.slack.com/api/users.channelSections.channels.bulkUpdate?_x_id=<redacted>&_x_csid=<redacted>&slack_route=<redacted>&_x_version_ts=1651772834&_x_gantry=true&fp=5e

remove: []
insert: [{"channel_section_id":"<redacted>","channel_ids":["<redacted>"]}]
token: <redacted>
_x_reason: channel-sidebar-channel-drop
_x_mode: online
_x_sonic: true
```

There is also `users.channelSections.create`, which appears to be involved in the creation of new sidebar sections.

I've attempted to use these endpoints, to no avail. As far as I can tell, I'm making the appropriate call, but the server returns status code 200 with the message `not_allowed_token_type`.

I've tested with various tokens, including the bot tokens prepended with `xoxb`, and my user token prepended with `xoxp`. In the browser, the token is prepended with `xoxc`, and my attempts to use this token in a direct call have resulted in the same `not_allowed_token_type` message with a status code of 200.

Has anyone worked with these endpoints before? It seems strange that they'd be undocumented. Any advice for next steps to try would be welcome.

Comment: Seems like they work with the session tokens, that are generated with Slack Client (browser/desktop).

Comment: Is "session token" a specific category of token? Yet another thing I'm not finding in their documentation. Do you know if there's a way to generate these tokens outside of a client instance?

Comment: what I mean by session token is the token that gets generated when you log into slack. It is not associated with any app but associated to you as a slack user.